# Can I find a set item more than once?

Tags: kingdoms-of-amalur-reckoning

I'm currently level 21 and I haven't encountered the same piece of set equipment (yellow items) twice. Can I find the same set item more than once?

I'm curious because I'm thinking about respecing and I've sold every set item I've encountered that wasn't related to my current class.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes,you can find the same piece of set item multiple times.

Source: Personal Experience

Proof:

[image: Proof]

Also if you don't have the luck to get the same items you sold you can just buy them off the merchants you sold them to but of course the price will be lot higher then what you got for them (But then again that doesn't really matter as getting the money if fairly easily and fast past lv10 and you will have so much money you wont know what to do with it anyway).

Comment: You're welcome.Have fun with your new class ^_^